# Default Weight-Paint Sample

Tags: bones, weight-painting, customization, shortcut

I'm trying to fine tune custom controls for myself but I'm having issues with selecting bones while painting weights.

In default Blender settings, when in the weight-paint mode, you can use  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Select Mouse</kbd> to select the joints quickly and continue painting. I have been trying to find the command in the Key configuration list for months now and I can't find the right command.

I've seen posts where people say it worked properly in Maya settings, but I've tried to get this working in both Windows and Linux Mint and Ubuntu with Blender 2.73 up to 2.78c

There is no command I can find that even suggests selecting bones or joints in blenders default controls. Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the bone using a right click (as selection is working like that in most Blender's function).

It is sometimes easier to select them using the properties panel.

[image]

For instance, when you are in selection masking modes, right click allows to select the model faces or vertices and not the bones:

[image]

Comment: Oh ya, I have done this. However, the bones i select some times are no where near each other alphabetically or any other way the list organises itself, and I end up scrolling up and down all the time comparing weights.

It would just be nice to figure out how to get the more natural, and efficient way of selecting the bone. Right now my solution is just switching back into original blender settings when weight painting.

Comment: So, you'd like ctrl+left click to select (or something similar)?

Comment: yes please, I also tried the right click select in the maya settings, and I get the toggle bones option.

Comment: So is the conclusion that there is no way to set that as a custom hot key? I'ts only a blender specific hot key right now?

Comment: @KevinR, if there is a way to do it, I don't know how